# Erro "undefined reference" ao compilar em C

Tags: c, compilação

Tenho um simples programa em que quando compila da um erro

> undefined reference to `incrementar'|

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "incrementar.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Numero incrementado%d!", incrementar(10));
    return 0;
}


incrementar.h:

int incrementar(int i)
{
    return i++;
}



incrementar.c:

int incrementar(int i)
{
    return i++;
}
```

Nota: estou a usar o Code::Blocks.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa compilar os dois códigos:

```
gcc -o main main.c incrementar.c
```

Se o Code::Blocks não colocou sozinho provavelmente criou o projeto de forma errada. Tem que ser com Project > Add Files.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tenho de compilar os dois códigos ao mesmo tempo ? E isso ?

Comment: Não necessariamente, mas a forma mais simples é esta.

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura de um TAD no code::blocks é composta das pastas Sources onde os arquivos com extensão .c devem ficar armazenados e a pasta Headers onde os arquivos .h devem ficar armazenados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a verificação das pastas utilize o botão direito em cada um dos arquivos selecione a opção properties, depois vá na aba Build nos arquivos com extensão .c deixe as opções compile file, link file, debug e release marcadas e para os arquivos com extensão .h deixe apenas as opções debug e release marcadas. Desta forma os arquivos pertenceram ao mesmo projeto.

Um erro notado no seu código é que você implementou a função incrementar em dois arquivos incrementar.h e incrementar.c o correto seria declarar a assinatura da função no arquivo incrementar.h e a implementação da função seria feita apenas no arquivo incrementar.c

Outro erro notado no seu código foi o return se você fizer return i++ a função retornará o mesmo valor porque o incremento será feito depois da exibição do resultado o certo seria return ++i. Segue as alterações feitas no código

Arquivo incrementar.h

```
int incrementar(int i);
```

Arquivo incrementar.c

```
#include "incrementar.h"
int incrementar(int i){

    return ++i;

}
```

Arquivo main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "incrementar.h"
int main()
{
   int valor,incremento;
   printf("Digite o valor a ser incrementado: ");
   scanf("%d",&valor);
   incremento = incrementar(valor);
   printf("Valor %d foi incrementado para %d",valor,incremento);
   return 0;
}
```